# The practice of identifying authors from their writings

Tags: linguistics, syntactic-analysis, science

Is there an English word for the practice of analysing texts to determine their authors?

For example, comparing three texts A, B and C and realising that the choice of words, grammar and style of writing between A and B is so similar that they're likely of the same author, while C is clearly by a different author.

Comment: See also: [linguistics.se]

Comment: Stylistic Analysis & Authorship Studies See Hugh Craig @ http://www.digitalhumanities.org/companion/view?docId=blackwell/9781405103213/9781405103213.xml&chunk.id=ss1-4-1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you're looking for *[**Stylometry**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stylometry)*:

> *Stylometry is the application of the **study of linguistic style**, usually to written language.*
>
> *Stylometry is often used to **attribute authorship** to anonymous or disputed documents. It has legal as well as academic and literary applications, ranging from the question of the authorship of Shakespeare's works to **forensic linguistics.***

Comment: Stylometry is 1. narrow -- covers only style. 2. broad -- extends today to art and music as well.

Comment: Stylistic Analysis & Authorship Studies See Hugh Craig @ http://www.digitalhumanities.org/companion/view?docId=blackwell/9781405103213/9781405103213.xml&chunk.id=ss1-4-1